# Cannot import Identical Github Fork of Python CoreMLTools

Tags: python, python-import, coremltools

I am having some issues using CoreMLTools, so I am going to try to debug it using my own Github repo. I forked the original project and modified nothing, but I get an error when I try to import it.

This works perfectly fine:

```
!pip install coremltools
import coremltools as ct
```

But this:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/[Owner]/[Repo Name].git 
import coremltools as ct # Identical Forked Copy of CoreMLTools
```

has the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1b9428219e3f> in <module>
      1 #!pip install coremltools
      2 get_ipython().system('pip install git+https://github.com/[Owner]/[Repo].git')
----> 3 import coremltools as ct

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/milproto/load.py in <module>
     25 from coremltools.converters.mil.mil.block import curr_block, curr_opset_version
     26 from coremltools.converters.mil.mil.ops.registry import SSAOpRegistry as _SSAOpRegistry
---> 27 from coremltools.libmilstoragepython import _BlobStorageReader as BlobReader
     28 from coremltools.proto import (
     29     MIL_pb2 as pm,

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coremltools.libmilstoragepython'
```

**EDIT:**
The following link seems to be a C++ file that does something with the module that can't be found.
https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/973eae67f2f273a29e80a9b009987516a070a58b/milstoragepython/MilStoragePython.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coremltools` does not build the `libmilstoragepython` source if you try to do a `pip install` of its source code - it would run `setup.py` which doesn't do any of the C++ compilation steps.

Instead, what you have to do is manually build the entire project and install the wheel file it generates. The main documentation for this is from their [`BUILDING.md`](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/main/BUILDING.md).

It looks like you're on some flavor of Linux, so you're probably going to need the following dependencies:

- C++ compiler with C++17 support (`gcc-8` or newer)
- `conda` (either [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) or Anaconda)
- `cmake` (either through package manager or installed from `pip`/`conda`)
- `zsh`
- `libuuid-devel` (your distro might call this `uuid-devel` or similar)

```
# You need conda installed and configured for zsh
# https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

# substitute your own coremltools fork here
git clone https://github.com/apple/coremltools/

cd coremltools

# You can specify whatever version of Conda-supported Python you want this for in the range of...
# 3.7, 3.8, 3.9
# I also assume you want debug mode
zsh -i scripts/build.sh --python=3.7 --dist --debug

# this will output many cmake messages, but hopefully it succeeds
```

After this, you will have a directory called `build/dist` that contains a `.whl` file that can be installed

```
ls build/dist
coremltools-6.0b2-cp37-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

I failed to mention that this was running in Google Colab. After running:

```
! /content/coremltools/milstoragepython/MilStorage.cpp
```

I got a message a permission denied message. It seems you can't run whatever c++ file you want in colab.

Comment: Running a `.cpp` file is rather meaningless, it's just text so it's not a valid executable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).